# Check user role in jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-security

I have  menu in jsp. There is link Home. But for user it is one, for admin it is other . 
How can I change it based on roles? I try this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">NG Market</a>
</div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')">
   <li><a href="/">Home</a> </li>
  </sec:authorize>
  <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    <li><a href="/user">Home</a> </li>
  </sec:authorize>
  <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <li><a href="/admin">Home</a> </li>
  </sec:authorize>
  <li class="active"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contactUs">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="javascript:formSubmit()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

But is doesn't work for me. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You already import <%@taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%> in your jsp?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work